# How to get inline svg animation working in IE

Tags: html, css, svg

I have been trying to get an line svg animation to behave consistently cross-browser but, Internet Explorer 11 is not beginning the animation on page load.

To simplify my question I have forked an example from [jczimmm](http://codepen.io/jczimm/)

I have removed any vendor prefixes to distill the CSS into its barest form so they can be re-added if needed.

Here is the [link](http://codepen.io/NicholasMurray/pen/MwNpge) to the fork on codepen.

Here is the svg

```
<div class="loader">
  <svg class="circular">
    <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

and here is the css

```
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.loader {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  zoom: 1.7;
}

.circular {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
          animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1,200;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  -webkit-animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite, color 6s ease-in-out infinite;
          animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite, color 6s ease-in-out infinite;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1,200;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89,200;
    stroke-dashoffset: -35;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89,200;
    stroke-dashoffset: -124;
  }
}
@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1,200;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89,200;
    stroke-dashoffset: -35;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89,200;
    stroke-dashoffset: -124;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes color {
  100%, 0% {
    stroke: #d62d20;
  }
  40% {
    stroke: #0057e7;
  }
  66% {
    stroke: #008744;
  }
  80%, 90% {
    stroke: #ffa700;
  }
}
@keyframes color {
  100%, 0% {
    stroke: #d62d20;
  }
  40% {
    stroke: #0057e7;
  }
  66% {
    stroke: #008744;
  }
  80%, 90% {
    stroke: #ffa700;
  }
}
```

Comment: CSS animations are not supported in IE 11 for SVG elements. It is supported in IE Edge apparently: https://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/csstransitionsanimationsforsvgelements/

Comment: well that makes sense